# What tools should programmers use for working on a Ubuntu machine from a Windows machine

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, development-environment, putty

Some of the developers have a Windows 7 machine, but would have to remote login into a Ubuntu machine for doing their work.

They either need to login into a remote AWS EC2 linux instance or a local Ubuntu machine in the LAN.

We currently use putty to login into the other machine, which provides a shell interface for programming (Ruby or Python apps) which is not quite convenient.

What tools should we use so that we get better productivity given the above limitations.

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate what "which is not quite convenient means".

Comment: Using putty to open a remote terminal and edit/run code is quite cumbersome.

Comment: So you want tools that will present a graphical UI to the Linux machine on the Windows box?

Comment: yes or anything other than putty which will make our lives better

Answer (score 3):

Revision control would work well for what you are doing. I would recommend setting up a shared git repository on the machine where the code will be. This will also allow developers to  collaborate without stepping on each others feet.

There are many GUI applications that interface with git, check out this question for that:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157476/what-guis-exist-for-git-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

For a graphical desktop login, you could use NoMachine's [NX](http://www.nomachine.com). That costs money. A free alternative is [x2go](http://www.x2go.org), which is also based on NX (the NX core is open source.)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VNC) locally  to "look" at an `xserver` running on the remote machine?